# Why image is not displaying in html mail in gmail?

Tags: c#, html, email

I'm trying to add an image in HTML mail. It is displaying when I save that **body** as **html file**, but when I send that **html body** as an email through **GMail**, the image is not displaying. Can anyone tell me the reason?

I set the source of the image in this way:

```
var image = body.GetElementsByTagName("img");
string imageAttachmentPath = Path.Combine(Globals.NotificationTemplatesPath, "Header.png");
foreach (XmlElement img in image)
{
    img.SetAttribute("src", imageAttachmentPath);
    break;
}

//thats the method in which i am sending email.

public static void SendMessageViaEmailService(string from, 
                                              string sendTo, 
                                              string carbonCopy,
                                              string blindCarbonCopy, 
                                              string subject, 
                                              string body, 
                                              bool isBodyHtml,
                                              string imageAttachmentPath, 
                                              Hashtable images, 
                                              List<string> attachment, 
                                              string title = null, 
                                              string embeddedImages = null)
{
    Attachment image = new Attachment(imageAttachmentPath);
    MailMessage msg  = new MailMessage();
    msg.IsBodyHtml   = true;                   // email body will allow html elements
    msg.From = new MailAddress(from, "Admin"); // setting the Sender Email ID
    msg.To.Add(sendTo);                        // adding the Recipient Email ID

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(carbonCopy))     // add CC email ids if supplied.
        msg.CC.Add(carbonCopy);

    msg.Subject = subject;                     //setting email subject and body
    msg.Body = body;
    msg.Attachments.Add(image);

    //create a Smtp Mail which will automatically get the smtp server details 
    //from web.config mailSettings section
    SmtpClient SmtpMail = new SmtpClient();
    SmtpMail.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    SmtpMail.Port = 587;
    SmtpMail.EnableSsl = true;
    SmtpMail.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    SmtpMail.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(from, "password");

    // sending the message.
    try
    {
        SmtpMail.Send(msg);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Would be better if we see your work also. Did you try to set your [`IsBodyHtml` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml.aspx) as well? Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: @VinodVT I have posted the code

Comment: @SonerGönül yes i have set it true. I posted the code of the method which i am using to send email.

Comment: Did you try to check the mail when it was received? You can check the source code of it.

Comment: @L33TS i have check the mail. Blank space is displaying in place of the image and In source code the image source is set.

Comment: @L33TS Image is displaying when i save the body as html but not in email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely your image SRC attribute is not an absolute, publicly-accessible URI. Any file-system or local URI's will not show the image in the email.

Specifically, these will not work:

```
c://test.png
test.png
/folder/test.png
http://localhost/test.png
http://internaldomain/test.png
```

Ensure that your image urls are

- absolute (i.e. start with the protocol like `http://`)
- includes a full path to the image
- the domain is a public domain

Answer (score -1):

Try the code part from [this thread](http://blog.devexperience.net/en/12/Send_an_Email_in_CSharp_with_Inline_attachments.aspx):

```
// creating the attachment
System.Net.Mail.Attachment inline = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(@"c:\\test.png");
inline.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
// sending the message
MailMessage email = new MailMessage();
// set the information of the message (subject, body ecc...)

// send the message
System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("localhost");
smtp.Send(email);
email.Dispose();
```